# updated to iOS4.1 and iAd "test advertisment" not showing up on simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, iad

I added the iAd as written in tutorials and in my app it always calls `didFailToReceiveAdWithError`. `bannerViewDidLoadAd` is never invoked. I know I'm supposed to see a "test advertisment" Ad, but nothing shows up, because the function `bannerViewDidLoadAd` is never being invoked.

I've looked into other questions, but didn't find an answer...
I would have added code, but I suspect this is more of a misunderstanding between me and Steve.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Can someone please let me know if this problem also shows him in the console:

> Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content" UserInfo=0xfdd4070 {ADInternalErrorCode=5, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Banner view is visible but does not have content}

Comment: If it changes anything, I'm using three20. What tells iAd it's not a real ad, and just to show the "test advertisment" ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check your iAd status for your application in your iPhone Development Portal. You must enable iAd access for your application there. This might take a couple of hours to activate (in my experience).

Also, I think the provisioning profile used for the application determines which ads should be shown. It states in the documentation that development and ad-hoc profiles show test ads and that the distributed version of your app shows the normal ads.

Comment: Even the "test advertisment" shouldn't show up without doing stuff at the iPhone Development Portal? I was under the impression this should be done only when I upload the app, and that it doesn't matter if I only test it on the simulator. Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I think it only shows up when you register your application for iAd support. But it is easy to check out right? Just add your application for iAds in:
iTunes Connect -> Manage your Apps -> Setup iAd Network

It's all really easy.

Comment: I did as you said and created a new app (after creating a new bundle) in itunes connect and enabled its iAds. I also created a distribution provisioning profile and dragged it onto my xCode. Then I updated the info.plist to match the profile. But, that didn't help the iAd to appear with the "test advertisement". Any ideas?

Comment: Did you also set the profile correctly for the debug version you are running? Distribution certificates are normally not for deploying on your phone.

Tried installing on your phone and the simulator? Any differences?

What does the error tell you when the failed function is called?

Comment: I'm getting "ADErrorDomain" as the error (not really sure what that means). I didn't try to install it on my phone, just on the simulator.

Comment: When I look under iAd Network I can see the new app id and "test ads enabled" for it. I think I've set the profile correctly for the debug version I'm running. I went to the info.plist file and updated the com.<company>.<appname> according to its profile. anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Another thing I think I should mention, is that this app wasn't built from scratch, I took a different project of mine, copied it, and than started changing.

Comment: and I don't have push notifications enabled.

Comment: You do NOT need to register for iAds to see the test advert.  I have just created a sample project and added a `ADBannerview`, the test advert loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that xcode 3.2.4 with iOS4.1 does not support iAd.
but i am downgrading the xcode to 3.2.3 with iOS4.0 and
still facing the problem of iAds testing does not display.

Any other reason.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.  It turns out that my certificates / provisioning profiles were all out of date.  Once I updated them, the problem went away without any further work.